# paste variable names together from 1 through 20 but without 20

Tags: r, paste

Simple question but can't seem to find an answer:

I have dummies from 1:20, but without dummy10. I want to stick the variable names together with "+" sign. The missing dummy is different in every model so  I will need to automate it somehow.

How do I automate this by leaving out the missing dummies?

This code below will not work, because it includes d10. I want the same thing but without d10.

```r
d<-as.factor(1:20)

library(dummies)
dat <-dummy(d, sep = "") # create dummies
dat <- dat[, -10] # take out dummy10

dummies <- paste("d", 1:20, collapse = " + ")
dummies
```

Thx

Comment: If what you want is the colnames in `dat` which start with `'dummy'` pasted together, you can `grep` the names directly, no need to create your own vector. `paste(grep('^dummy', names(date), value = TRUE), collapse = '+')`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan: Yes, this is what I am looking for, but your code doesn't seem to work. It gives me " ". I've also tried `paste(grep('^d', names(dat), value = TRUE), collapse = '+')` , also doesn't work.

Comment: If `dat` is a matrix and not a data.frame you need to replace `names(dat)` with `colnames(dat)`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan: Yes, that was it. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dummies <- paste("dat", c(1:9, 11:20), collapse = "+")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_c` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_c("dat", c(1:9, 11:20), collapse="+")
```